# linux invalid group name error

Tags: linux, permissions, user

I trying change owner of a directory. There was a mess before that about /etc/group file. There was a group named "500" and oinstall group id was 15001. I changed these configs manually via group file and I rebooted the system.

After that I check the directory for user and group and these like "oracle 500". There is no group named "500" in /etc/group I used "chown" command for change the group 500 to oinstall but system gave an error like this:

`` [root@myserver /]# chown -R oracle:oinstall /dir
chown: invalid group: `oracle:oinstall' ``

note:

```
[root@myserver /]# getent passwd oracle
oracle:x:500:500::/home/oracle:/bin/cdax/bash

[root@myserver /]# getent group oinstall

[root@myserver /]# chown -R oracle:oinstall /dir
chown: invalid group: `oracle:oinstall'

[root@myserver /]# grpck -r
'rooty' is a member of the 'rooty' group in /etc/group but not in /etc/gshadow
no matching group file entry in /etc/group
delete line 'arda:!::'? No
no matching group file entry in /etc/group
delete line '500:!::'? No
grpck: no changes
```

oinstall /etc/group file:

```
[root@myserver /]# cat /etc/group | grep oinstall
oinstall:x:500:
```

I can see oinstall in group file but still chown/chgrp command doesn't work correctly:

```
[root@ANIPTORCLT01 /]# chgrp oinstall /dir
chgrp: invalid group: `oinstall'
```

Comment: chown treats numeric values as user/group **IDs** not user/group **Names**. https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown

Comment: actually chown allows name i knew so. I use chown with name always. btw i tried with id but didn't work.

Comment: Please provide the output of both `getent passwd oracle` and `getent group oinstall`.

Comment: i added the outputs to end of question @Charley

Comment: cuz there is no output of getent oinstall @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: sorry for my attention. but the output is same, empty.

Comment: I've read your comment under my answer (and I still think you should add the `groupadd ...` fragment to your question). I cannot replicate the issue. For now I think there may be some elusive error or inconsistency in your `/etc/group` and/or `/etc/gshadow`. Can you add a group with another name? Can you add a group with another `gid`?

Comment: I added oinstalll group with 3 "l" letters and 50000 gid but there is no difference about error. invalid group. I can see it in gshadow and group files as correct. But error is there still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the nsswitch file passwd shadow and group lines to winbind from centrify and the problem is solved.